# user wants to apply a quite complex "User Search Filter" in his LDAP Configuration

Tags: ldap, documentum

user have to apply a quite complex "User Search Filter" in his LDAP Configuration.
The filter is too big and exceed the 256 allowed character. For customer business policy is not possible to modify the LDAP structure or data How can we proceed?
Here there is a sample of the filter:

```
(&
    (|
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_AmmApplicativo,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_AmmPiattaforma,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_ArchFIRead,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_ArchFIWrite,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_AreaFinanza,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_Arm,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_BoGestCanc,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_BoUpdDocum,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_Crif,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_VisualBase,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
        (memberOf=CN=Applicazione_DocB_VisualEsteso,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
    )(|
        (userAccountControl=512)
        (userAccountControl=544)
        (userAccountControl=66048)
    )
)
```

Comment: I formatted your query to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Have the customer create one single group to control access to the application, then they can add all of those groups to that one group. Then you only need to look at that one group. However, you will need to use the [`LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) operator so that it will look at the members of nested groups.

If the name of that new group is `Applicazione_DocB`, that would look something like this:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Applicazione_DocB,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)
```

Your conditions on `userAccountControl` can also be simplified. That attribute is a bit flag, which means that each bit in the binary value is a flag that means something. Those values are listed in [the documentation for `userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol#remarks). The three conditions you are using are:

- 512: `ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT`
- 544: `ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD` (password not required)
- 66048: `ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD` (password does not expire)

If the intent is to exclude disabled accounts (514: `ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE`), then you can do that by using the [`LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND`](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND) operator to check if the second bit is *not* set (which indicates a disabled account), like this:

```
(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
```

Putting that all together, you get a query that is less than 256 characters:

```
(&(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Applicazione_DocB,OU=Intranet,OU=Gruppi,DC=CBMAIN,DC=CBDOM,DC=IT)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```